# How to hide routes in spa from being watched in app.js bundle?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, security, routes, single-page-application

As you know, one of the security measures is preventing everyone from being able to see all site routes and showing them what they need to and they should only see.

I want to fix this problem for `SPA` web apps, in which all `routes` are plain in the final build app.js ( even it has been uglified). So I want to know how should I do this? ( i already test some methods but didn't get the right result.)

**update**

I know that every method using in `SPA` for this kind of use will eventually include the routes in the `spa` in the final bundle `app.js`. as you know in the `code obfuscation` world, one way is to pack(`encrypt`) the sensitive data, so nobody can see it in plain text, and show it at runtime when the user actually needs it.

I know it is not a perfect solution, but I believe, it will increase security as a layer.

Comment: the only way is to switch to SSR else every piece of your code will be visible for everyone. That's how every SPA works.

Comment: Yes, I know how SSR work, but I think it can be archived in SPA with some proper methods(like instant encryption, etc...), and I liked to know other developer's experience...

Comment: A server should never deliver any sensitive content unless there's a user logged in with proper access rights; how that content is presented to the user is largely irrelevant; if your SPA shows, say, admin-only content to an arbitrary visitor if they happen to know the obscured route, then your app is broken anyway.

Comment: No framework known to me currently does such a thing. This would be troublesome also, because SSR will impact performance. If I had to build such a thing, I would probably build several different web clients for different user roles.